# Discord.py: How to make command_prefix non case sensitive?

Tags: python, discord

I need help, So I created a Discord Bot with this `Command Prefix "ija` " how to make a non-case sensitive so i can type it like this `"iJa"` or this `"IJA"`

> ```
> client = discord.Client()
>
> client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'ija ')
>
> @client.event
> async def on_ready():
>     await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name='Do "ija 3aweni"'))
>     print('Everything is ready, Bot ready to rock!')
> ```

input: ija,
output: Bot does respond

input: iJA,
output: Bot does respond

input: IJA,
output: Bot does respond

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter for this called `case_insensitve`. If you wanted a subset of those words you can also pass a list to `command_prefix`.

Comment: It appears that the `case_insensitive` option is for the command name and not the prefix. The list is probably the only option.